# How detect when a record is loaded in a TDBEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using a  `TDBNavigator` component in a TForm to navigate over the records of a Dataset, and I need disable a specific `TDBEdit` component when the value of a field has a particular value. So what event of the TDBEdit or the TDataset I can use to check when a new a record is "loaded" and in that way check the value of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for TDataset events yields lots of answers.  I'd look at OnAfterScroll for your requirements.